# Create array with a normal distribution

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a vba array of size N, with normally distributed percentages that add 100%. This means that with an input of an integer number N, I should get as output a n-sized array with values that sum 100 and is normally distributed

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: @ScottCraner ...I agree, but it is a very simple code, just wanted some help on the normal distribution part, which I don't know how to do

Comment: A quick search of "fill array normal distribution vba" gave a lot of starting points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious so I did one.

```
Sub NDArray()
Dim arr() As Double
a = InputBox("Number of numbers")

ReDim arr(a - 1) As Double
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    'fill the array with random numbers that fit a normal dist
    For i = 0 To a - 1
        '"A/100" is the target mean and "A/200" is target Std. Dev, change to your desire
        arr(i) = .Norm_Inv(.RandBetween(1, 1000) / 10000, a / 100, a / 200)
    Next i
    'change the numbers to percentage of whole and multiply by 100 to get the values to sum to 100
    x = .Sum(arr)
    For i = 0 To a - 1
        arr(i) = (arr(i) / x) * 100
    Next i
    'post the numbers in Column A on the active sheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(a).Value = .Transpose(arr)
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
Sub NDArray()
a = InputBox("enter the integer")
ReDim arr(a - 1)
For i = 0 To a - 1
arr(i) = 100 / a
Next i
End Sub
```

But I also agree with Scott... Try to write the code first and post your issues...

Comment: This will return an array of the same number.  OP wants it [Normally Distributed](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/normal.htm).  It is a good start for the OP but this will not do what is asked.

Comment: Thank you very much @AvinashKumar ...I had the same code, the part with the normal distribution is what I have no idea how to do